# Explain the difference:

Tags: c++, c, operators

```
int i=1,2,3,4;  // Compile error

// The value of i is 1

int i = (1,2,3,4,5);

// The value of i is 5
```

What is the difference between these definitions of i in C and how do they work?

Edit: The first one is a compiler error. How does the second work?

Comment: Pretty sure this falls under undefined behavior

Comment: @Kippie the second one is using the comma operator. Many times.

Comment: First one is a compiler error

Comment: @icepack yes, or at least it should be.

Comment: ...so what's the point discussing bad behavior of some weird compiler?..

Comment: Abhinav I am curious, what compiler accepted your first example?

Comment: @juanchopanza the first was a compiler error indeed. My bad..

Comment: @juanchopanza it appears that the OP has recognized his error, and has removed that example.

Comment: "compiler error" is not the same as "compile-time error". Software development is a discipline that requires precise communication.

Comment: @Kippie Why are you pretty sure of that? It certainly isn't true.

Answer (score 7):

`=` takes precedence over `,`<sup>1</sup>. So the first statement is a declaration and initialisation of `i`:

```
int i = 1;
```

… followed by lots of comma-separated expressions that do nothing.

The second code, on the other hand, consists of one declaration followed by *one* initialisation expression (the parentheses take precedence so the respective precedence of `,` and `=` are no longer relevant).

Then again, that’s purely academic since the first code isn’t valid, neither in C nor in C++. I don’t know which compiler you’re using that it accepts this code. Mine (rightly) complains

> error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

---

<sup>1</sup> Precedence rules in C++ apply regardless of how an operator is used. `=` and `,` in the code of OP do not refer to `operator=` or `operator,`. Nevertheless, they are *operators* as far as C++ is concerned (§2.13 of the standard), and the precedence of the tokens `=` and `,` does not depend on their usage – it so happens that `,` *always* has a lower precedence than `=`, regardless of semantics.

Comment: I think it's misleading to say that = has greater precedence than comma operator in the context of the (invalid) first line. That comma is not acting as an operator there.

Comment: The equals sign isn't an operator either.

Comment: @Cubbi the `=` character most definitely is an operator - it responds to the operator precedence, and is overloadable in C++ as well.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII he meant _that_ one isn't an operator, and he's right.

Comment: @Cubbi It most definitely is. You are right that it isn’t `operator=` but that’s not what I said.

Comment: @jrok Sorry, wrong. It’s not `operator,` but that’s not what I said. It **is** an operator anyway, and its precedence is governed by the same syntactic rules regardless of its semantic role. (And the same goes for `=` which, while not being `operator=`, is still an operator with the same precedence.)

Comment: @Konrad sorry if my comment attracted a herd of downvoters, I'm not one of them :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think they are saying that (a) that is initialization, not assignment (b) if `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` were correctly used, that would **not** have been `operator,`. Now, the initialization point is only half-moot, since the assignment operator is required to be accessible, even if it is actually elided.

Comment: @sehe I do not understand that comment. I am not talking semantics. I am not talking about the distinction between initialisation and assignment, and that distinction is not relevant for precedence. Precedence for the tokens `=` and `,` is always the same in C++. It doesn’t matter which semantics they fulfil.

Comment: Konrad: I agree. However, you were asking what people were (wrongly) downvoting you for... @jrok What "invalid first line" are you referring to? I can't see one. Also note that the question was edited.

Comment: @cnicutar Yes, I’m slightly annoyed. Hence the now added “PS” on my answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Cool explanation. Would upvote again if I could.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't downvote, but some confusion could come from the fact that you mention that the first variant is illegal almost as an afterthought. Also, to say that the comma separated expressions in the first statement "do nothing" is not entirely correct, since they render the entire statement illegal.

Comment: `they are operators as far as C++ is concerned (§2.13 of the standard)` this is wrong, 2.13 does not name these tokens as operators. but I see what you're coming from: the precedence of operators is a special case of expression grammar (5.17,5.18), and in the declaration grammar (8.5), these tokens have similar "precedence" (= is between `declarator` and `initializer-clause`, while comma separates the entire `init-declarator`s

Comment: @Cubbi Well okay, to be **very** precise, “preprocessing operators and punctuators” but the standard subsumes that under the shorthand name `lex.operators`.

Comment: "the = character most definitely is an operator" -- No, it most definitely isn't. It's a *token* that sometimes is an operator, but isn't in this context. Same for `,`.

Comment: "Precedence for the tokens = and , is always the same in C++." -- This is utter nonsense. Tokens don't have precedence, operators do. Precedence applies when the grammar is otherwise ambiguous, but there is no ambiguity here because `=` is an explicit token in the grammar, *not an operator*.

Comment: "this answer has received a significant number of downvotes due to apparent misconceptions about C++ precedence rules" -- This is false, as no one has expressed any misconception of C++ precedence rules. Even if they had, this sort of defensive accusation, and reference to how people have voted, has no place in an SO answer.

Comment: @Cubbi *in the declaration grammar (8.5), these tokens have similar "precedence"* -- those scare quotes are well deserved because that has nothing whatsoever to do with operator precedence.

Comment: @Jim The C++ grammar makes no distinction whatsoever between “precedence” of operators vs. other grammatical constructs. “ Tokens don't have precedence, operators do” – I challenge you to find that in the C++ standard (you won’t). The precedence of different constructs is simply implicit in the grammar (and *that* point is even made explicit, in a footnote). And since there’s this discussion raging in the comments I *do* feel that a clarification (not an “accusation”) does have its place in the answer proper.

Comment: "I challenge you to find that in the C++ standard (you won’t)" -- It's in *computer science*; you are misapplying a term of art. As for the C++ standard, precedence is mentioned in the footnote you mention, on *expression syntax*; it refers to the precedence of *operators in an expression*, not to "constructs". And your comment *is* an accusation and an inappropriate comment about downvoting that has nothing to do with the question asked; as such it does not belong in the answer and you know it. End of discussion for me.

Comment: @Jim I am aware of the conventions in computer science and I don’t believe I misapplied them here. We can argue for months about poorly defined terms in CS but that’s clearly unproductive. I tried to give an intuitive answer to this question – and the intuitive answer is in terms of precedence: `=` binds with higher strength than `,`. You claim that precedence is about expressions. Fair enough. But there is no hard-and-fast distinction between expressions & other constructs. And when challenged on the level of C++ standard parlance I answered on that level but I don’t think this is fruitful.

Comment: @Jim You and others seem to argue from a strictness of definition that simply doesn’t exist – either in the C++ standard or in parser theory. If you take issue with this answer I invite you to write your own which answers OP’s question about the effect of parentheses here without invoking “precedence”, and which is still understandable instead of convoluted.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about C++, but at least for C the first one is invalid syntax so you can't really talk about a declaration since **it doesn't compile**. The second one is just the comma operator misused, with the result 5.

So, bluntly, the difference is that the first isn't C while the second is.

Comment: The question is not about being valid code. It's about the result it gets.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There is no result to discuss since the code doesn’t compile.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII the answer would have to be "what compiler are you using?"

Comment: @KonradRudolph Correct. As such I have removed the downvote. The original downvote was because the first revision of this was clearly a FGITW post.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Everything I added was "The second is just...". The rest is noise. The main part of my answer pointed out the first line is illegal syntax. I feel I've added nothing essential in between. Also, downvoting should be used as a way to mark incorrect or useless answers, not "We need to punish this behavior".

Comment: "The question is not about being valid code. It's about the result it gets. " -- According the standard, the result it gets is a diagnostic.

Answer (score 6):

You have run into an interesting edge case of the comma operator (`,`).

Basically, it takes the result of the previous statement and discards it, replacing it with the next statement.

<s>The problem with the first line of code is `operator precedence`. Because the `=` operator has greater precedence than the `,` operator, you get the result of the first statement in the comma chain (1).</s>

Correction (thanks @jrok!) - the first line of code neither compiles, nor is it using the comma as an operator, but instead as an expression separator, which allows you to define multiple variable names of the same type at a time.

In the second one, all of the first values are discarded and you are given the *final* result in the chain of items (5).

Comment: You're discussing the result of first line of code in OP, while it doesn't even compile.

Comment: @jrok Of course it doesn't. I was answering the question in the OP as to what he expected. Just because his specific line of code doesn't compile, doesn't change the fact that the `=` operator has more precedence than the `,` operator.

Comment: Well, the comma is not acting like a operator there, but rather a separator :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII nor it change the fact that Rome is the capital of Italy. Same relevance (+ jrok's comment)

Comment: @jrok well then by that logic you should have downvoted Konrad's answer as well. His was 30 seconds behind mine and has that same logic flaw.

Comment: I'm pondering that right now, hehe. I'll hapilly remove the downvote if you fix it. (EDIT: downvote removed)

Comment: @jrok thank you for pointing that out. I never use the multiple variable syntax like that, simply because I find it harder to read.